# why does pip installation throw this error?

Tags: python, pip

```
$ sudo easy_install pip ( on mac high sierra)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==18.5', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 484, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2707, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2325, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2331, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 46, in <module>
    from setuptools.archive_util import unpack_archive
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/archive_util.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import ensure_directory, ContextualZipFile
ImportError: cannot import name ContextualZipFile


$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: have you tried doing pip3, or install pip using ``` sudo apt install python3-pip```

Comment: I would try @andypaling1 suggestion too

Answer (score 3):

You should try firstly installing pip by using these commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

If you are installing it for python2:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip
```

Then you can verify the version using:

```
pip3 --version
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are having two versions of python installed on your mac. 
First is the Python 2.x (which is default) and Python 3.x. 
This is a problem I too faced a lot earlier, so what I suggest is this

```
$sudo apt install python3-pip
```

This will explicitly install the pip for Python 3.x 
And once completed use a virtual environment.